# Child component not being updated with funcional components

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where I get repositories like below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    loadRepositories();
  }, []);

  const loadRepositories = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/mcand/repos');
    const data = await response.json();
    setUserRepositories(data);
  };
  return (
   <Repository repositories={userRepositories} /> 
  )
```

The child component  only receives the repositories and prints them. It's like that:

```
const Repository = ({ repositories }) => {
  console.log('repository rendering');
  console.log(repositories);

  const [repos, setRepos] = useState(repositories);
  useEffect(() => {
    setRepos(repositories);
  }, [  ]);
  const getRepos = () => {
    repos.map((rep, idx) => {
      return <div key={idx}>{rep.name}</div>;
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <RepositoryContainer>
        <h2>Repos</h2>
        {getRepos()}
    </>
  );
};

export default Repository;
```

The problem is that, nothing is being displayed. In the console.log I can see that there're repositories, but it seems like the component cannot update itself, I don't know why. Maybe I'm missing something in this useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're putting the repository data from props into state, then then rendering based on *state*, when the props change, the state of a Repository doesn't change, so no change is rendered.

The repository data is completely handled by the parent element, so the child shouldn't use any state - just use the prop from the parent. You also need to `return` from the `getRepos` function.

```
const Repository = ({ repositories }) => {
  const getRepos = () => {
    return repositories.map((rep, idx) => {
      return <div key={idx}>{rep.name}</div>;
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <RepositoryContainer>
        <h2>Repos</h2>
        {getRepos()}
    </>
  );
};

export default Repository;
```

You can also simplify

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadRepositories();
}, []);
```

to

```
useEffect(loadRepositories, []);
```

It's not a bug *yet*, but it could be pretty misleading - your child component is named `Repository`, yet it renders multiple repositories. It might be less prone to cause confusion if you named it `Repositories` instead, or have the parent do the `.map` instead (so that a `Repository` actually corresponds to one repository array item object).

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setRepos(repositories);
  }, [  ]);
```

to

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setRepos(repositories);
  }, [repositories]);
```